# JQGrid paging very slow after applying filter via filter toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with LOAD ONCE and then paging on the client side. When I add in a filter toolbar, paging becomes very slow after any sort of filter is applied.

```
$(gridElement).jqGrid({
        postData: post,
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            onLoadComplete(data); 
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            onGridComplete(); 
        },
        datatype: function (pdata) {
            dataSource(pdata);
        },
        colNames: columnNames,
        colModel: columnModel,
        rowNum: 10, 
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        viewrecords: true,
        pagination: true,
        pager: pagerElement,
        loadonce: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        sortname: 'id',
        cellEdit: false,
        search: true,
        gridview: true,
        //rownumbers: true
    });


    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{ 
        stringResult : true, 
        searchOnEnter : false });
```

Any idea why this occurs? There is a delay when clicking the paging button, before any of the common events fire (like onPaging, onGridComplete, etc.).

Note that once the grid is complete, datatype property is set to 'local'.

My guess is that it tries to filter every time you page (or it only filters one page at a time? not sure). But can that be disabled?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a live example of this?

Comment: The origin of the problem could be `onLoadComplete` and `onGridComplete` functions. Why you need both of the functions instead of usage just `onLoadComplete`? Why you use `datatype` as function? Moreover you use posted `colModel` just as `columnModel`. One need to understand what you do to be able to helps you. Could you include much more details (inclusive code) in your question. The best would be the demo which reproduces the problem which you have,

Comment: I think what Enzino posted might be the problem..is client-side filtering with loadonce: true typically slow?

Comment: @SeanThoman: The answer depends on many details. Has the grid 10 or 40 columns? Has the grid 100 or 10000 rows? Many implementation details in `columnModel`, `onLoadComplete` and `onGridComplete` can make the working on the grid slowly. I suppose you need to solve *you problem* and have less interest on common discussions. In the case you should post more details about your implementation.

Comment: @SeanThoman I'm not sure if this helps. But [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/) provides a much better client-side performance for larger grids, than any other free alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to alternative grid libraries, I suggest you take a look at [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/).

I've been using it for a while now. Seems to be the best in class JavaScript grid library.
Once you get a hang of it, its easy to customize & also has quite a number of plugins already.

Comment: Lot of code though (separate file / http requests). Also, the author should add a README.md file to the repo.

Comment: @JoeJohnson I assumed that finally you would be using a JS, CSS minifier like [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) or something like [WRO4J](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) in your build process.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into using DataTables (http://www.datatables.net) as a replacement. The sorting is, I believe on the entire data set (which would make it very slow to process this script -- and then bind events). I recently researched options for table sorting and grid layouts -- I went with DataTables over jqGrid due to performance issues.

In addition, see if getting the latest version doesn't help speed things up ... http://www.trirand.com/blog/ (new release in June).